# Angular2 / Ionic2: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '()' is not a valid attribute name.

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-components

I have the problem, that no matter how I put it i won't get my custom component to accept the parameters I send it.

I tried different approaches like with {{}}, '' or without "" but in the end I get the same **Error** if it does compile to the point of the template:

*Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '()' is not a valid attribute name.*

---

I tend to use the latest releases, which are bundled by the ionic-cli (2.1.17):

- Angular: 2.2.1
- Ionic: 2.0.0 - rc.4
- Typescript: 2.0.9
- rxjs: 5.0.0 - beta.12

---

The basic class is
**substitute-helper.ts:**

```
    export class SubstituteHelper {
        number: number;
        kind: string;
    }
```

This is imported into **substitute.ts:**

```
    import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
    import {SubstituteHelper} from '../../app/substitute-helper';

     @Component({
        selector: 'substitute',
        templateUrl: 'substitute.html'
     })
     export class SubstituteComponent {
        @Input()
        sub: SubstituteHelper;
     }
```

This is then used in **application.ts**:

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
    import {OverviewPage} from "../overview/overview";
    import {SubstituteHelper} from '../../app/substitute-helper';

    @Component({
        selector: 'page-application',
        templateUrl: 'application.html'
    })
    export class ApplicationPage {
        showSubstituteVar: boolean = false;
        subs: Array<SubstituteHelper>;
        subNo: number = 0;

        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

        addSubstitute(kind: string) {
            var sub = new SubstituteHelper();
            sub.number = this.subNo;
            sub.kind = kind;
            this.subs.push(sub);
            this.subNo += 1;
        }
```

In the **HTML-template** file I try and fail to use this:

```
    <div *ngIf="subs.length>0">
        <div *ngFor="let substi of subs">
            <substitute [sub]="substi"></substitute>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you imported "SubstituteComponent" in your application.ts?

Comment: where is addSubstitute called? when is subs set?

Comment: can you please add as plunker

Comment: As a small code review for you, you should always use interfaces when passing data and not classes. Classes have a constructor, a prototype a bunch of other things that you just don't need. An interface can represent a simple {} object

Comment: This might not apply to this case but is relevant to similar error messages: If one leaves off the ending > of the start tag, one can get strange error messages.  One such error message I received was 'Element': '--' is not a valid attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing by reading the code and from what is show there. I found two possible issues:

- `<div *ngIf="subs && subs.length>0">` (`subs` is probably `undefined` at that time)
- `subs: SubstituteHelper[] = []` (initialize the value)

Answer (score 0):

Without the ***ngIf** and the **()** I put in a tag above, this is what solved this error for now.

```
    <div *ngFor="let substi of subs">
        <substitute [sub]="substi"></substitute>
    </div>
```